# how to set validation rules in foreach loop in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation

I need to set rules dynamically I don't know what will be the name of input type. For example I have input type`<input type="text" name="first_name">` I can set rule for it like

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules("first_name", "First Name", "required");
```

But I am doing it dynamically suppose I have `$_POST` array I don't know the input type name value. So I did it this way

```
foreach($post as $key => val){

  $this->form_validation->set_rules($key, remove_underscore($key), "required");      

}

$this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters("<p class='text-danger'>", "</p>");

    if($this->form_validation->run()){
      //do stuff here..
    }
```

The validation does not work in this loop way. If I set rules in a string and echo it outside the loop like

```
$str = '';
   foreach($post as $key => val){
     $str .= '$this->form_validation->set_rules($key'
   }

   echo $str;
```

That doesn't work either because I have to do `echo json_encode(var)` at the end. If I echo it first it will stop there only. I hope I have clear my point, if any one can guide me I will appreciate.

Comment: what does "does not work" mean? what errors have you experienced and debugging steps have you taken?

Comment: if($this->form_validation->run()){ echo true }{else false)         goes on false

Comment: So echo validation errors to see what is wrong